# Why does my computer freeze up when updating the preview window in cycles with gpu compute?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Whenever I update a material with the rendered preview window open my entire computer freezes up and requires a reboot. This only occurs in cycles when using gpu compute. I have linked to a video showing how this occurs only with gpu compute. I can also link to the .blend is necessary.

Thanks for any help or ideas!

After further research I have found that amd gps are not completely compatible with blender cycles, could this be the reason for the crash?

[image]

[Video](https://goo.gl/photos/UogitR1re34dAtHCA)

Comment: What kind of GPU are you using?

Comment: My gpu is an amd R9 390

Comment: I think the issue you are having has to do with the limited support to AMD GPUs... You might need to work using CPU only...

Comment: This could depend on the scene being rendered. OpenCL is at least [partially supported](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html) and was used for [GPU test renderings by AMD](http://developer.amd.com/community/blog/2015/07/10/collaboration-and-open-source-at-amd-blender-cycles/). Note that card they used was older. According to [the list of AMD GPUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units#Radeon_HD_7xxx_Series) your card *should* be supported. And of course try to update drivers for GPU (if not yet).

Comment: Alright thanks, I will just have to stick with CPU then for that scene at least.

Comment: I'd suggest [reporting this to the blender devs](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1377/599), though it's possibly a driver-side issue. Either way, something isn't working as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the User preference and check for 2 things.

1. Is the correct Graphics card listed in the Compute Device section?
2. Is CUDA enabled or if your GPU actually support CUDA?

**UPDATED ANSWER**
Yes there is a limitation on the support for AMD GPU unfortunately, at the
moment it's pro nvidia. Feb 2016.

[image]

Comment: No, it uses openCL